# div side by side and float left

Tags: html, css

eftMy html:

```
<div id="content_living" >
    <div id="leftnav">
    //only text href
    </div> 
    <div id="show_pics">
    //pics: 1, 2, 3 4, - all href with img
    </div> 
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#content_living {

}

#leftnav{
float:left;
width:200px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 30px;
background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);  
}

#show_pics {
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 10px;
width: auto;
}
```

What I get:

```
href1  | pic1 pic2 pic3
href2  | pic4 pic5 pic6
       | pic7 pic8 pic9
       | pic10 pic11 pic12
```

But what I want:

```
href1  | pic1 pic2 pic3
href2  | pic4 pic5 pic6
| pic7 pic8 pic9 pic10
| pic11 pic12 ...
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You have lnav and leftnav. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display:inline` to #show_pics

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3k4H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try floating your navigation to the left and then just add a padding to your content div. Should suffice as a dirty solution for your problem.

```
.left-nav {
    float:left;
    width:90px;
    background:darkgray;
}
.main-content {
    padding-left:100px;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/QWhSn/

Answer (score 0):

You're better off putting floated element inside the same parent as the content that is supposed to wrap around it. So remove the `div` around the pics.

I knocked this up so you could see http://jsfiddle.net/FE3Wj/

Answer (score 0):

That's only my solution:

Give `#content_living` a width. Than add a `float: right;` command to the `#show_pics` id and delete the `float: left` command from `#left_nav`. With the width in the `#content_living` you can control the space between the two div's inside. Hope it works.